# Iphone: Zombie Trace Template Not Available in Xcode 4.0 For iOS Device?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

How do enable Zombie trace template in XCode 4.0 for an iOS device. When I run it using simulator the Zombie option is displayed but with device it is not.. There is no way to enable it? FYI, I have set the option `NSZombieEnabled`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have a zombie crash that only occurs when running my app on the device.  It works fine when running in the simulator.  This is with Xcode 4.1 running on Mac OS X Lion against iOS 4.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Zombie trace template is available for Simulator only and it cannot used for Device. Reason I could not find as yet though.